# How to make dynamic time in select box with 5 minutes interval?

Tags: php

I need dynamic time select box with 5 minutes interval in php. Anybody help me?

```
<select name="time" id="time">
 <option value="5:00 AM">5:00 AM</option>
 <option value="5:05 AM">5:05 AM</option>
 <option value="5:10 AM">5:10 AM</option>
 .
 .
 .
 .
 <option value="23:55 AM">23:55 AM</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `DateTime`:

```
$dateTime = new DateTime('5:00 AM');

for($i=0; $i <= 515; $i++) {
    echo $dateTime->format('H:i A'), "\n";
    // add 5 minutes
    $dateTime->modify('+5 minutes');
}
```

You can use `modify` to add how many minutes you want.